# Count rows if the values are in two columns within a range and same direction using R

Tags: r, count, range, direction

I have a table in data table format. I need to perform the following calculation in R.

```
Table1: 

Cty           Pred      Trend
Adams         -9.193    -15.81
Alexander     -1.143      3.01
Bond           5.95     -14.05
Boone          0.57       3.63
.
.
```

I need to count the number of "Cty" if the values in "Pred" and "Trend" columns are in the same direction (i.e. negative or positive) and if the values are within +/- 5% of the value in "Trend" column.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first conditional checks that both Pred and Trend are in the same direction.

The second conditional checks that Pred is within 5% of the Trend values.

The result is the number of cities where both conditions are satisfied (assuming there are no duplicate city names).

```
sum(with(df, ((Pred>0) == (Trend>0)) & (abs((Trend-Pred)/Trend)<=0.05)))
```